Error: Exception while trying to deploy a Flask App using 'scikit-learn' on Vercel
I am using a Flask application in the file named as app.py in my root directory and another python file to create the ML model named as regressor.py.
I tried deploying the repository on Vercel numerous times but got the same error while processing my requirements.txt file.
This is the error from logs:
Error: Command failed: pip3.12 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . 
--upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt


ERROR: Exception:

I am trying to host a Flask application which uses some ML modules that are described in the requirements.txt file as follows:
Flask==2.2.2
matplotlib==3.6.3
numpy==1.24.2
pandas==1.5.3
scikit_learn==1.5.1

I have an app.py which has the Flask code and another regressor.py which holds the training model. I created the proper vercel.json, index.py, and wsgi.py as instructed in a tutorial online.
These files look as follows:
vercel.json
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src":"./index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python",
            "config":{"runtime":"Python3.11.4"}
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src":"/(.*)",
            "dest":"app.py"
        }
    ],

  "installCommand": "pip install -r requirements.txt"
}

index.py-
from wsgi import app

wsgi.py-
from app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8000)

My file structure looks like this:
/
static
    assets
    data_prime
    datasets
    styles
templates
app.py
index.py
wsgi.py
regressor.py
requirements.txt
vercel.json


You are importing some heavy-duty libraries: matplotlib is ~36MB, numpy is ~19MB, scikit_learn is ~7MB, and pandas is ~5MB. That, coupled with a hefty dataset, is probably exceeding the max space allowance for Vercel's serverless functions.
You should probably not be uploading your dataset to Vercel. Instead, train your model locally, compress it using joblib and gzip, and upload the compressed model to Vercel. Then, on Vercel you can unzip/load your model and use it as you would normally.
If you don't want to deal with Vercel's space limitations, you might consider using a virtual private server (e.g. DigitalOcean or AWS) instead.
